# Ocamlyacc token not visible when performing semantic action

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ocaml, yacc, ocamlyacc

I am using `ocamlyacc` for a small parser which also performs some semantic actions on most parsing rules.

I have defined a set of tokens in the beginning:

```
%token T_plus
%token T_minus
%token <int> T_int_const

%left T_plus T_minus
```

A parser rule which performs a semantic action is the following:

```
exp:  exp T_plus exp
      {
          checkType T_plus $1 $3
      }
```

where `checkType` is an external helper function. However, I'm getting this strange warning (which refers to a line in my `Parser.mly` file)

```
 warning: T_plus was selected from type Parser.token. 
 It is not visible in the current scope, 
 and will not be selected if the type becomes unknown.
```

I haven't found any relevant info in the ocamlyacc manual. Has anyone encountered a similar error? Why is the token not visible inside the scope of the semantic action?

Comment: Everytime that I saw this error, the developer missed an ``Open``.

Comment: @alifirat the warning refers to `T_plus` *inside* Parser.mly and more specifically inside the semantic action's scope. I suspect that is has to do with `T_plus` being a constant constructor but I haven't encountered anything similar in the past.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post all the code ?

Comment: Do you have any other `T_plus` definition that in the `%token` line ?

Comment: @PatJ no, apart from the precedence annotation (see last edit).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to guess what goes wrong on your side, since you're not disclosing enough information. I can guess, that you somehow misread the error message, and the problem is in another file. For example, the following file:

```
%{
 let f PLUS _ =  ()
%}

%token PLUS
%left PLUS

%start exp
%type <unit> exp

%%

exp : exp PLUS exp {f PLUS $1}
```

compiles any problems or warnings with

```
ocamlbuild Parser.byte
```

I can only suggest, to look at the generated `Parser.ml` and see what's is happening there.

In general, this message means, that you're referring to a constructor, that was not brought to the scope. In `Parser.mly` tokens are always in the scope, so you can't see this error in that file. Usually, you may do this in your lexer. So make sure, that you have `open Parser` in the intro section of your lexer.